# Opening Windows 10 DMP file

Tags: windows, debugging, memory-dump

Which program would you success to open a Windows 10 `.DMP` file.

I've tried OllyDbg110(32Bit)
but this is the result:

[image: error msg]

Do I have to use a 64bit debugger or am I on a totally wrong route?

Comment: You need a 64-bit debugger to debug a dmp from a 64-bit process.

Comment: Also tried with 64Bit OllyDbg...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/3433/18014) RE answer OllyDbg can't be used directly to analize dumps.

You should use either [WinDbg](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0)(this Preview or old version) or [VisualStudio](https://www.visualstudio.com/). They can load .DMP files directly and allow anlyzing them.